# WIX: remove property from log file

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

I'm working on a Wix installer and executing with the following command:

```
msiexec /i MyInstaller.msi /l*v log.log
```

In the installer, I defined the following property:

```
<Property Id="SECRETPROPERTY" Secure="yes" Hidden="yes"/>
```

The verbose log file shows the property name while hiding its value:

`Adding SECRETPROPERTY property. Its value is '**********'.`

But apart from its value, I also do not want others to know of the existence of the property and hence they will not set it. Is it possible to hide the entire property including its name? I want the entire line above to not appear in the log file. How is it done?

Comment: If you declare the property name, then it is going to be in the MSI file, and anyone can see it with Orca or an MSI file viewer. After install the MSI will be cached in \installer where it could be viewed. If you really want to completely hide the existence of SECRETPROPERTY an MSI file/log is not the right place. Perhaps its functionality could be replaced with something like a C++ custom action that removes the need for the existing design.

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Refers to Hidden Property's link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa370308.aspx)

> When the Debug policy is set to a value of 7, the installer will write
>   information entered on a command line into the log.

I believe the your debug policy is set to 7.

Comment: I guess I didn't state my question clearly. What I'm targeting to achieve is to hide the property from being log completely regardless of the level of debug policy. The solution you provided solves the problem on the user side but they are still able to change the debug policy to view everything.